# Generic Object Editing Classes with Controller, ViewModelProvider and DBUpdater

Tags: c#, mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc

I am beginning to use generics and would like feedback on the following set of classes that will serve as the basis for an app that contains a large number of basic CRUD-y entities.

I have used `Car` and `Person` classes as examples, but there will be a whole bunch of basic classes like these, perhaps 50 +.

My aim is to make maintenance / adding more of these classes as painless as possible, but also to allow for deviations when they arise. With that in mind, for the `Person` class I have:

- added a custom action / viewmodel
- added a different method signature for Index, that will allow filtering by the Starsign property

The Repository layer should be flexible and allow non-enumerated selections. The ViewModelProvider is the cut off point and all methods should return enumerated data.

I'd really appreciate your opinions on this code and any suggestions for improvement.

**Entity Base Classes**

```
public interface IDBEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    List<string> PreventDeleteReasons { get; }
    bool IsDeletable { get; }
}

public class DBEntity : IDBEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name",
        Description = "")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be more than {1} characters long ")]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }



    // just override this to prevent delete
    // protected: The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.
    protected virtual List<string> GetPreventDeleteReasons()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    // no need to override these
    public virtual List<string> PreventDeleteReasons
    {
        get
        {
            if (_PreventDeleteReasons == null)
            {
                _PreventDeleteReasons = GetPreventDeleteReasons();
            }
            return _PreventDeleteReasons;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    private List<string> _PreventDeleteReasons { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeletable
    {
        get
        {
            return (PreventDeleteReasons.Count == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Entities**

> ```
> public class Person : DBEntity, IDBEntity
> {
>     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Starsign { get; set; }
>     protected override List<string> GetPreventDeleteReasons()
>     {
>         List<string> reasons = base.GetPreventDeleteReasons();
>         if (Starsign == "Aquarius")
>         reasons.Add("Aquarians are too cool to be deleted");
>         return reasons;
>     }
> }
> public class Car : DBEntity, IDBEntity
> {
>     public virtual string Model { get; set; }
>     public virtual string Colour { get; set; }
>     protected override List<string> GetPreventDeleteReasons()
>     {
>         List<string> reasons = base.GetPreventDeleteReasons();
>         reasons.Add("It's a really nice car");
>         reasons.Add("You need to get to work every day");
>         return reasons;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Repository**

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : DBEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> AllAsQueryable(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions);
    List<T> AllAsList(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions);
    List<T> SelectAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions);
    List<T> SelectAllWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereBit, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions);
    T SelectByID(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions);
    void Create(T obj);
    void Edit(T obj);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Save();
    void Dispose(bool disposing);
}


public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> 
    where T : DBEntity
{
    private ApplicationDbContext DB = null;
    private DbSet<T> Table = null;


    public GenericRepository()
    {
        DB = new ApplicationDbContext();
        Table = DB.Set<T>();
    }



    public virtual IQueryable<T> AllAsQueryable(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        return includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
            (Table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
    }

    public virtual List<T> AllAsList(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        return includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
         (Table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression))
         .ToList();
    }



    public virtual List<T> SelectAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        return AllAsQueryable(includeExpressions).ToList();
    }

    public virtual List<T> SelectAllWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereBit, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        return AllAsQueryable(includeExpressions).Where(whereBit).ToList();
    }


    public virtual T SelectByID(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        if (includeExpressions.Any())
        {
            var set = includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                     (Table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

            return set.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
        }
        return Table.Find(id);
    }



    public virtual void Create(T obj)
    {
        Table.Add(obj);
        Save();
    }



    public virtual void Edit(T obj)
    {
        Table.Attach(obj);
        DB.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Save();
    }



    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = Table.Find(id);
        Table.Remove(existing);
        Save();
    }



    public virtual void Save()
    {
        DB.SaveChanges();
        //Save();
    }



    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            DB.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public interface IItemVM<T>
{
    T Item { get; set; }
}
public class GenericItemVM<T> : IItemVM<T>
    where T : DBEntity
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}



public interface IItemListVM<T>
{
    List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
public class GenericItemListVM<T> : IItemListVM<T>
    where T : DBEntity
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}



public interface IAttemptDeleteVM<T> : IItemVM<T>
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    bool IsDeletable { get; }
    List<string> PreventDeleteReasons { get; set;  }
}
public class GenericAttemptDeleteVM<T> : GenericItemVM<T>, IAttemptDeleteVM<T>
    where T : DBEntity
{
    // p'less constructor populates PDR?
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeletable
    {
        get
        {
            return PreventDeleteReasons.Count == 0;
        }
    }
    public List<string> PreventDeleteReasons { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Entities**

> ```
> public class PersonIndexVM : GenericItemListVM<Person>
> { }
> public class PersonAquariansVM : GenericItemListVM<Person>
> {
>     public string Title { get; set; }
> }
> public class PersonDetailsVM : GenericItemVM<Person>
> { }
> public class PersonCreateVM : GenericItemVM<Person>
> { }
> public class PersonUpdateVM : GenericItemVM<Person>
> { }
> public class PersonAttemptDeleteVM : GenericAttemptDeleteVM<Person>
> { }
>
>
>
> public class CarIndexVM : GenericItemListVM<Car>
> { }
> public class CarDetailsVM : GenericItemVM<Car>
> { }
> public class CarCreateVM : GenericItemVM<Car>
> { }
> public class CarUpdateVM : GenericItemVM<Car>
> { }
> public class CarAttemptDeleteVM : GenericAttemptDeleteVM<Car>
> { }
> ```

**ViewModel Providers**

```
public interface IVMP<T, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteViewModel>
    where T : DBEntity, IDBEntity
{
    GenericRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }
    TIndexVM Index();
    TCreateVM Create();
    TCreateVM Create(TCreateVM postedModel);
    TDetailsVM Details(int id);
    TUpdateVM Update(int id);
    TUpdateVM Update(TUpdateVM postedModel);
    TAttemptDeleteViewModel AttemptDelete(int id);
}
public abstract class GenericVMP<T, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM> //: IVMP<T, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM>
    where T : DBEntity, new()
    where TIndexVM : class, IItemListVM<T>, new()
    where TDetailsVM : class, IItemVM<T>, new()
    where TCreateVM : class, IItemVM<T>, new()
    where TUpdateVM : class, IItemVM<T>, new()
    where TAttemptDeleteVM : class, IAttemptDeleteVM<T>, new()
{
    // shd be public? if not kill from iface
    public GenericRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }

    public GenericVMP()
    {
        Repository = new GenericRepository<T>();
    }
    public TIndexVM Index()
    {
        // all to list, so need repo
        return new TIndexVM()
        {
            Items = Repository.AllAsList()
        };
    }
    public TDetailsVM Details(int id)
    {
        return new TDetailsVM()
        {
            Item = Repository.SelectByID(id)
        };
    }
    public TCreateVM Create()
    {
        return new TCreateVM()
        {
            Item = new T()
        };
    }
    public TCreateVM Create(TCreateVM postedModel)
    {
        return new TCreateVM()
        {
            Item = postedModel.Item
        };
    }
    public TUpdateVM Update(int id)
    {
        return new TUpdateVM()
        {
            Item = Repository.SelectByID(id)
        };
    }
    public TUpdateVM Update(TUpdateVM postedModel)
    {
        return new TUpdateVM()
        {
            Item = postedModel.Item
        };
    }
    public TAttemptDeleteVM AttemptDelete(int id)
    {
        var item = Repository.SelectByID(id);
        return new TAttemptDeleteVM()
        {
            ID = id,
            Item = item,
            PreventDeleteReasons = item.PreventDeleteReasons
        };
    }
}
```

**Example Entities**

> ```
> public class PersonVMP : GenericVMP<Person, PersonIndexVM, PersonDetailsVM, PersonCreateVM, PersonUpdateVM, PersonAttemptDeleteVM>,  IVMP<Person, PersonIndexVM, PersonDetailsVM, PersonCreateVM, PersonUpdateVM, PersonAttemptDeleteVM>
> {
>
>     public PersonAquariansVM Aquarians()
>     {
>         return new PersonAquariansVM()
>         {
>             Title = "Viewing Just Aquarians",
>             Items = Repository.SelectAllWhere(p => p.Starsign == "Aquarius").ToList()
>         };
>     }
>
>     public PersonIndexVM CustomIndex(string id)
>     {
>         return new PersonIndexVM()
>         {
>             Items = Repository.SelectAllWhere(m => m.Starsign == id).ToList()
>         };
>     }
> }
> public class CarVMP : GenericVMP<Car, CarIndexVM, CarDetailsVM, CarCreateVM, CarUpdateVM, CarAttemptDeleteVM>, IVMP<Car, CarIndexVM, CarDetailsVM, CarCreateVM, CarUpdateVM, CarAttemptDeleteVM>
> { }
> ```

**DBUpdaters**

```
public interface IDBU<T, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM>
{
    void Create(TCreateVM model);
    void Update(TUpdateVM model);
    bool AttemptDelete(TAttemptDeleteVM model);
}
public abstract class GenericDBU<T, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM> //: IDBU<T, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM>
    where T : DBEntity, new()
    where TCreateVM : class, IItemVM<T>, new()
    where TUpdateVM : class, IItemVM<T>, new()
    where TAttemptDeleteVM : class, IAttemptDeleteVM<T>, new()
{
    // is ok private?
    private GenericRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }


    public GenericDBU()
    {
        Repository = new GenericRepository<T>();
    }

    public void Create(TCreateVM model)
    {
        Repository.Create(model.Item);
    }
    public void Update(TUpdateVM model)
    {
        Repository.Edit(model.Item);
    }
    public bool AttemptDelete(TAttemptDeleteVM model)
    {
        if (model.Item.IsDeletable)
        {
            Repository.Delete(model.ID);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Example Entities**

> ```
> public class PersonDBU : GenericDBU<Person, PersonCreateVM, PersonUpdateVM, PersonAttemptDeleteVM>, IDBU<Person, PersonCreateVM, PersonUpdateVM, PersonAttemptDeleteVM>
> { }
> public class CarDBU : GenericDBU<Car, CarCreateVM, CarUpdateVM, CarAttemptDeleteVM>, IDBU<Car, CarCreateVM, CarUpdateVM, CarAttemptDeleteVM>
> { }
> ```

**Controllers**

```
public class GenericController<T, TVMP, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM, TDBU> : Controller
    where T : DBEntity, new()
    where TVMP : IVMP<T, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM>, new()
    where TIndexVM : class, new()
    where TDetailsVM : class, new()
    where TCreateVM : class, new()
    where TUpdateVM : class, new()
    where TAttemptDeleteVM : class, new()
    where TDBU : IDBU<T, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM>, new()
{


    private GenericRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }
    private IVMP<T, TIndexVM, TDetailsVM, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM> VMP { get; set; }
    private IDBU<T, TCreateVM, TUpdateVM, TAttemptDeleteVM> DBU { get; set; }


    public GenericController()
    {
        VMP = new TVMP();
        DBU = new TDBU();
        Repository = new GenericRepository<T>();
    }




    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        TIndexVM vm = VMP.Index();
        return View(vm);
    }


    public virtual ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        TDetailsVM vm = VMP.Details(id);
        return View(vm);
    }


    public virtual ActionResult Create()
    {
        var vm = VMP.Create();
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(TCreateVM postedModel)
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DBU.Create(postedModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(postedModel);
    }




    public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var vm = VMP.Update(id);
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(TUpdateVM postedModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DBU.Update(postedModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(postedModel);
    }


    [ActionName("Delete")]
    public virtual ActionResult AttemptDelete(int id)
    {
        var vm = VMP.AttemptDelete(id);
        return View(vm);
    }

    // POST: People/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var vm = VMP.AttemptDelete(id);
        bool success = DBU.AttemptDelete(vm);
        if (success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View("AttemptDelete", vm);
    }
}
```

**Example Entities**

> ```
> public class PeopleController : GenericController<Person, PersonVMP, PersonIndexVM, PersonDetailsVM, PersonCreateVM, PersonUpdateVM, PersonAttemptDeleteVM, PersonDBU>
> {
>     private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
>
>
>     // custom methods here
>
>     private PersonVMP PersonVMP = new PersonVMP();
>
>     public ActionResult Aquarians()
>     {
>         var vm = PersonVMP.Aquarians();
>         return View(vm);
>     }
>
>
>     [NonAction]
>     public override ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         throw new SystemException();
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult Index(string id)
>     {
>         PersonIndexVM vm;
>         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
>         {
>             vm = PersonVMP.Index();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             vm = PersonVMP.CustomIndex(id);
>         }
>         return View(vm);
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> public class CarsController : GenericController<Car, CarVMP, CarIndexVM, CarDetailsVM, CarCreateVM, CarUpdateVM, CarAttemptDeleteVM, CarDBU>
> {
>     private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
>
>
>     // custom methods here
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `IDBEntity`, `IGenericRepository<T>`, `IItemListVM<T>`, `IAttemptDeleteVM<T>`

You are exposing a `List<string>` via a property which shouldn't been done. Assume you want/need to change this to another type which say is implementing `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` but isn't a `List<T>` then the caller/user of your interface would need to change his/her implementation. A `List<T>` is an implementation detail which shouldn't be exposed.

See also: [CA1002: Do not expose generic lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx)

#### `DBEntity`

```
// no need to override these
public virtual List<string> PreventDeleteReasons
```

so why is this property  `virtual` ? If it shouldn't be able to be overridden then remove the `virtual` keyword and also that comment.

### General##

Based on the [Net naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) variables should be named using `camelCase` casing. See `DB` and `Table` in `GenericRepository<T>`.

Comment: thank you - that's very helpful. Now making those changes